# TWebBrowser - prevent new windows

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I have a `TWebBrowser` that opens a website and I want to prevent it from creating new windows when I click on links.

I prefer to show the new URL in the same window that contain the browser .
is there any way to do that?

Comment: In what way is this related to Delphi. Surely it's an issue for this browser. Whatever it is.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the VCL [`TWebBrowser`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser) component, it has an [`OnNewWindow2`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.OnNewWindow2) event, which has a `Cancel` parameter:

> Cancel allows the event handler to block the creation of a new window. **When the event handler sets Cancel to true, the Web browser tries to display the target resource in its current window**, starting with an OnBeforeNavigate2 event.

Comment: thank you  for help